# What shall I learn in order to understand Auslander-Reiten theory and tilting theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I work on cluster algebras and quivers and hence I need to understand Auslander-Reiten theory and tilting theory as soon as possible. I have read some noncommutative algebra and homological algebra but still have trouble pondering on Auslander-Reiten-Smalo's book, Representation Theory of Artin Algebras. Without Auslander-Reiten theory I can not understand tilting theory, either. May I ask what shall I learn in order to understand both of them? Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you be more specific about what noncommutative algebra and homological algebra you know? I read most of that book recently, and those are pretty much what I would recommend as prerequisites.

Comment: For homological algebra I use Osborne's Basic Homological Algebra. I have read Ext, Tor, most of category-theoretical abstract homological algebra and half of the derived functors. I have not read enough about dimensions though I know the basic definitions.
For noncommutative algebra I only know some basics together with something about the Jacobson radical. I have not done many exercises and can not solve most noncommutative algebra problems here, though I generally understand the terminology. I only started to read noncommutative algebra one or two weeks ago using Prof. Pete Clark's Notes.

Comment: Then noncommutative algebra is definitely where you need to focus, though you also do need to know a bit about what happens to the homological algebra when the ring is not commutative, since this complicates a few things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the book *Elements of the Representation Theorey of Associative Algebras* by Assem, Simson, & Skowroński.  It covers both Auslander-Rieten Theory, Tilting Theory, and almost all of the background required to understand those chapters.

Comment: One guy at a conference I attend recommend the same. Although reading Hugel's notes and directly reading Auslander-Reiten-Smalo is possible, I will still try to check out this book, which exists in the library.